# Access global variable with same name as instance variable

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var myVar = 5;

var example = function() {
   var myVar = 10;

   // How can I access the global variable 10?
};
```

If there is a global variable with the same name as a local variable, how can I access the global one?

I am not using es6.

I am running it in jsdb, not a browser or node so I do not have access to objects 'Window' or 'global'

Comment: If there is no global object, I don't think it's possible. Best to use different variable names regardless, though.

Comment: How / where are you calling `example()`? Are you able to alter that code at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can alter the code calling your `example()` function, you should be able to pass the current scope using [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and access it using `this`. For example

```js
'use strict'

var myVar = 5;

var example = function() {
   var myVar = 10;
   
   console.info('Local:', myVar)
   console.info('Outer:', this.myVar)
};

example.call({ myVar })
```

Comment: Thanks... I guess I'm confused on why 'this' accesses the global scope as opposed to the local scope, while inside the example function. Can you explain that more for me?

Comment: It doesn't. `this` in the function access the function's context. The handy thing about `Function.prototype.call` means you can supply this context. For example, if you used `.call({a: 1})` then `this.a` would be `1`.

Comment: This answer uses ES6 which would be fine but the OP says he is not using ES6. Just change { myVar } to { myVar: myVar }

Comment: @PHPGuru yet OP accepted the answer 